# Cannot retrieve data for some exchanges from Google Finance

Tags: google-sheets

Since last weekend, I encounter problems retrieving data from exchanges such as SGX and SHA.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(SGX:ES3,changepct)
=GOOGLEFINANCE(SHA:000001,changepct)
```

The error message is;

> When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, Google Spreadsheets is not authorized
>   to access data for exchange: 'SHA'

Anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Looks more like a Google support question; if their server can't access the data form some exchange, that's what it is.

Comment: [It looks like it's recent and it's not just you](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/HDnOnJc8MRE/fcLS-3ckDwAJ) and I've seen no solution yet.

Comment: Yes, I am facing the same issue. Google has not yet given any clarification. For updates, see: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HDnOnJc8MRE

Comment: I wonder which are the exchanges that have been affected besides the ones I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The [Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) file includes:

> GOOGLEFINANCE is only available in English and does not support most international exchanges.

[Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/HDnOnJc8MRE) (Juln 16/12/15):

> Due to issues beyond our control, the following exchanges are no longer supported in Google Sheets: TYO, INDEXTYO, BKK, INDEXBKK, SHA, INDEXCSI, SGX, & KLSE.

For a solution, maybe scrape a web page.